# To mock a method returning void

Tags: easymock, powermock

I am fairly new to writing mock classes.I am trying to write a test class for the below method and I am not able to proceed with mocking the method call "getSsnValue".

```
public void setFieldValue(String fieldValue) {
    final Field<String> SSN = getSsnField(fieldValue);

    if (SSN !=null) {       
        getSsnValue(SSN ,fieldValue);
    }
}
```

Below is the test written for mocking the method "getSsnField" and is working fine.Can anyone help in understanding how to mock the void method "getSsnValue" so that this method will not be executed during the call "controller.setFieldValue(name);"

**Code Snippet:**

```
controller = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Controller.class).addMockedMethod("getSsnField",String.class).createMock(); 
EasyMock.expect(controller.getSsnField((String)EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(SSN).anyTimes();                
EasyMock.replay(controller);           
controller.setFieldValue(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you mocking those methods because they do some heavy-lifting that you can't afford to do in your test? The reason I ask is because, IMO, if you have to create a partial mock like this in order to mock out calls to methods that live in the same class then you are probably testing at a too fine-grained level. In other words, do you really need to mock out those methods?

I also assume that, if you do want to mock those internal methods out then the only reason for the test must be to ensure that if getSsnField(fieldValue) returns a Field, that getSsnValue() is invoked with the same fieldValue.

If you want to continue down that path, here's what you need to do. In EasyMock, to mock out a void method, you don't use expect(...); Instead you just call the method directly on your mock object (before calling replay()).  Doing so instructs EasyMock to create the expectation that that void method will be called.

```
Controller controller = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Controller.class)
    .addMockedMethod("getSsnField", String.class)//
    .addMockedMethod("getSsnValue")//
    .createMock();
Field<String> SSN = new Field<String>();
String name = "name";
EasyMock.expect(controller.getSsnField(name)).andReturn(SSN).anyTimes();
// Just calling the getSsnValue method on the mock sets up the expectation
// that it must be called
controller.getSsnValue(SSN, name); // Mocking void method here
EasyMock.replay(controller);
controller.setFieldValue(name);

// This step is needed in order to enforce that all mocked methods were
// actually called.
EasyMock.verify(controller);
```